# How to setup multi-tenant rails app with an admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, multi-tenant, apartment-gem

I am having a problem with how will I correctly set the models of my rails application. I will use the gem [Apartment](https://github.com/influitive/apartment) for multi-tenancy and the gem [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for authentication.

What I want to achieve is that I will have 3 user levels. The **admin**, **owner**, and **user**.

Basically, the **admin** handle all **owners** in the site, he can add, edit, and delete **owners**. Imagine that **admin** owns the whole website (https://example.com).

The **owner** will handle **users**, he can add, edit, and delete **users**. If the **admin** owns (https://example.com) then the **owner** only owns (https://owner1.example.com).

Each subdomain will have its own **users** handled by the **owner**. And all owners are handled by the **admin**.

What I have come up currently is having 2 models.

- WebsiteAccount
- UserAccount

WebsiteAccount will have **subdomain** and **owner_name** columns.
UserAccount will have **email**, **password**, and **user_level**. Where user_level can be **owner** or **user**.

Then the Devise will be used on **UserAccount** model. The UserAccount model will only show data based on the subdomain.

Now the question is where does the **admin** account fall?

Do I create a separate model for it and also use Devise gem on that?

Comment: You're talking about a "superadmin", or an admin of all tenant applications. That's usually a regular user with a different flag, or membership to a "house account" that signifies superadmin status.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can work with same table and just adding role to each user, admin, owner and user (different table for roles or just boolean attribute for each one) and then just play with conditionals on this or some before_filter to validate that certain type of user can access to different views or run some actions. Doesn't seems too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the apartment gem, you will need to create a new Devise user model for the 'admin' (e.g. AdminUser) and add that model to the config.excluded_models in your apartment config file: https://github.com/influitive/apartment#excluding-models. This will make AdminUsers records available at the top level domain. You can't just add a role to the UserAccount model because those records are scoped to each apartment 'tenant'.

You will also need to add WebsiteAccount to the config.excluded_models for apartment to allow those to be managed at example.com. This is assuming that you want WebsiteAccount to be your apartment 'tenants'.

To manage the UserAccount for each WebsiteAccount, you'll need to either manage that within each WebsiteAccount's subdomain, or do some tenant switching at example.com to gain access to and assign a UserAccount to a WebsiteAccount.